# onCreateOptionsMenu not working properly

Tags: android, android-menu

I have this recurring issue with the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method. I have it set up so it enables or disables options depending on the value of some `SharedPreferences`, but for some reason the first time you open the menu it doesn't work as it should, the options that should be disabled are enabled and the other way around. If I close it and reopen it, it works fine.

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    menuConfig(menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    menuConfig(menu);
    return true;
}

public void menuConfig(Menu menu){
    menu.getItem(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.MENU_ABOUT)).setEnabled(true);
    if (preferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.PREFS_STARTED), false)){
        menu.getItem(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.MENU_START)).setEnabled(false);
        menu.getItem(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.MENU_STOP)).setEnabled(true);
    }else{
        menu.getItem(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.MENU_START)).setEnabled(true);
        menu.getItem(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.MENU_STOP)).setEnabled(false);
    }
    if(!preferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.PREFS_STARTED),false) && preferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.PREFS_FILES_CREATED),false)){
        menu.getItem(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.MENU_DELETE)).setEnabled(true);
        menu.getItem(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.MENU_SET_ID)).setEnabled(true);
    }
    else{
        menu.getItem(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.MENU_DELETE)).setEnabled(false);
        menu.getItem(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.MENU_SET_ID)).setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

These two pics are taken subsequently with a few seconds between each menu key press.
[image: First menu key press, WRONG]
[image: Second menu key press, RIGHT]

The first one is wrong, it should look like the second one.

Comment: I believe it is due to the fact that I inflate before calling menuConfig, but I tried doing it the other way around and it crashed.

Comment: I even tried forcing the initial state through the menu layout xml and it does not work, which means that the preferences are being read but wrongly, for some reason.

Comment: There's no need to call `menuConfig` from `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onPrepareOptionsMenu` as the prepare method is called anyway even after the create method is called (which happens only once). So you can safely remove the call from the create method.

Comment: Still doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: when/where do you read the preferences?

Comment: That's not in the code you posted...

Comment: I didn't post the onCreate method actually.

Comment: Oh sorry I thought you meant the createOptionsMenu() method.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the default value returned by the queries to the `SharedPreferences` object but I have no idea of what is actually happening.